# Visual Studio Asp.net Website Compilation error: Child nodes not allowed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

"**Child nodes not allowed**" seems to be notorious compilation error on Asp.net website if you do some googling.

**Environment**: WinXp, VS2008 and VS2008 SP1, .NET 3.5 SP1

**Behavior**: create a brand new Asp.net website (not web application), then just build it, you got compilation error "Child nodes not allowed" on the Web.config on line where it says providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>

I got this problem after I re-installed vs2008.  Now, a lot of people are suggesting fixes but none worked for us.  Only one guy mentioned he successfully got rid of this problem by re-installing windows, but we don't want to go that far if we don't have to.  There is another person who opened a ticket to MS but hasn't gotten back a response yet.

If there is anyone out there who has similar environment like us and know how to get around this problem, we'd really appreciate it!!!

**Edit**  The weirdest part of all this is that I don't know how I got it.  It is a brand new box and brand new installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague just found a fix for this dreadful problem, it is a .NET Framework Cleanup Utility at http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog|_Tools/dotnetfx20|_cleanup|_tool.zip

Just download, run and restart your machine and re-install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (since the cleanup util removes all the .NET Frameworks for you)!  Really hope this could help others who have the same problem, it's been 4 days fighting with this one issue, thanks Microsoft!

Thank you guys very much for your input, I voted up for you both, appreciate it!

Ray.

Comment: Will do in 48 hours, SO rule!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reinstall Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: You have it, but did you reinstall it after you reinstalled VS2008?

Comment: yeah i think i did, but i'm installing it again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got that specific error, but try the following (if you haven't already):

- Since you re-installed the vs 2008, try re-applying the SP1
- Clear all the asp.net temporary folders it generates for the web sites.